# Google maps on Swift 4

Tags: swift, google-maps

Im building an app with google maps, and i would like to show a route between 2 static points
I was folling [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=od-ffVxyt78) tutorial but i can't make it yet, for some reason it dont show the route.

I dont want to make an dinamic route i just want it from two point that i´ve define

here's some code

GMSServices.provideAPIKey("MY API KEY")

```
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 19.0660043, longitude: -98.12050499999998, zoom: 18.0)
    mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    view = mapView

    var source = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(19.060914, -98.125935)
    var destination = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(19.1660043, -98.13000)
```

plx help

Comment: Remove your API key

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a path first and then use that path to create a polyline

```
let path = GMSMutablePath()
path.add(source)
path.add(destination)
let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
polyline.strokeColor = UIColor.red
polyline.strokeWidth = 3.0
polyline.map = self.map
```